# keyboard comes up with date picker

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, textbox

Using latest Xcode 8.2 Beta and Swift 3.  Saw some Swift examples for DatePicker using a text box to display the date and have it working. My problem is that a keyboard comes up first when you tap on the date input textbox.  If I put anything in the text field and do a few more returns in other fields, the DatePicker starts working like it should (the DatePicker comes up when you tap on that field and you can input a date).    So how do I get only the DatePicker to come up when you tap on a Date field?   My Sent Event is "Did End on Exit".  Put in a lot of resigFirstResponder to see if I could knock the keyboard down but they dont' seem to have much affect.  I initialize the TextBox with the current date but I'm pretty sure it works the same with no initialization.  I have two textfields/DatePickers.  Here is my code for one of them:

```
func datePickerChangedSell(sender: UIDatePicker) {

    resignFirstResponder()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .medium
    sellDateDisp.text = formatter.string(from: sender.date)

    resignFirstResponder()


}

    @IBAction func sellDateAction(_ sender: UITextField) {
    let datePicker:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date
    sender.inputView = datePicker
    resignFirstResponder()
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerChangedSell(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
    resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What causes a date picker to display when you activate your text field is the line `sender.inputView = datePicker`. You should do that in viewDidLoad, not in an `IBaction`.

The reason it works after editing the text field, swapping to another field, and then swapping back must be that you're invoking your sellDataAction method, which is assigning the text field's `inputView`.

Comment: Thanks for the help.    Tried to move the sender.InputView up to viewDidLoad and got unresolved reference about sender.   Tried to add "_ sender: UITextField" inside the parens of viewDidLoad and it said something about no overrides from methods superclass.   So will try to understand your suggestion better.

Comment: You need to create an outlet to your text view in the view controller that manages it. Open the Storyboard and then open the view controller's source file in the accessory editor. Control-drag from the text view into your source file, and give the text view a name. Then reference that name in the call that sets the text view's `inputView`

Comment: Duncan, thanks i'll give that a try.   I think I'll try it in a separate build first.   I have a lot of objects here and I find the connections hard to undo if you make one and it doesn't work.   Get it right, then implement on my product build.

Comment: Outlet connections are actually easy to undo. Try this in your test project. Link up an outlet, and then find the inspector tab that's called the "connections inspector." Find the outlet connection you made, and if you hover over it, an X highlights. Click that X and it breaks the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Duncan, Thanks for the help, I figured this out and you got me there.   I tried to mark your answer as the answer but it wouldn't let me.   My problem was that I created the Action as "Editing Did End" rather than "Editing Did Begin".  When I deleted the textbook and re-added the Action the DatePicker came up the first time without the text keyboard.  One question, is there a way to just change Editing Did End to Editing Did Begin? I see the circle with the arrow where it shows all the Edit options, but it didn't seem to let you change it.  It seemed like I had to drop and re-add the text box.   One other point of reference.   It wouldn't let me connect the text box directly inside the viewDidLoad method.  It insisted that I Connect it somewhere else.

Comment: One interesting side effect.   With Editing Did End it would save the last date I input for the session, even when I tapped on the date.   When I went to Editing Did Begin it puts my initial value in the next time I tap on that Date textbook.

Comment: Also Editing Did End is the default so others may have this problem.